# how to capture outgoing soapclient request?

Tags: php, soap-client

I've tried a couple of potential solutions (using ob_ for instance) I found, but not having any luck.

I'd like to be able to display to screen the outgoing request in order to debug it.

Answer (score 2):

I've debugging of SoapClient by extending the [SoapClient](http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php) and overriding methods like [_*soapcall()*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapcall.php) and [_doRequest()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.dorequest.php). In my projects I have a logger that writes the XML/arguements to a file.

My example includes both **_*soapCall()*** and **_doRequest()**. I print out different stuff in both methods. Might suit your debugging needs. I like to read the $args output from __soapCall() and like to copy the XML into [SoapUI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SoapUI) for validation (Alt+V). HTTP headers might also be interesting if you are debugging authentication or other error situations.

```
class MySoapClient extends SoapClient {
    public function __soapCall ($function_name, array $args, array $options = null, $input_headers = null, array &$output_headers = null) {
        // Dump $args to file, browser printout, console, etc
        var_dump($args);

        parent::__soapCall ($function_name, $args, $options, $input_headers, $output_headers);

        // XML request and response:
        var_dump($this->__getLastRequest()); // Request sent to server
        var_dump($this->__getLastResponse()); // Response from server

        // HTTP headers:
        var_dump($this->__getLastRequestHeaders());
        var_dump($this->__getLastResponseHeaders());
    }

    public function __doRequest ( string $request , string $location , string $action , int $version, int $one_way = 0 ) {
        var_dump($request); // XML

        $response = parent::__doRequest ($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way);
        var_dump($response); // XML

        return $response;
    }
}

$webservice = new MySoapClient('http://example.com/myservice?wsdl');
$webservice->__soapCall('SomeOperation', array($someArguments));
```

A logger can be used instead for var_dump:

```
logger('debug', $this->__getLastRequest());
```

Comment: For the life of me, I can't figure out why I can't override __soapCall. I defined the function as you have provided and it does not get picked up.